# Java getter/setter generation with Lombok for code with annotations

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I use [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) to automatically generate getter and setter methods for all fields of a Java class.

When a field is annotated with e.g. `@XmlTransient`, the annotation is not propagated to the generated getter/setter methods, thus in the resulting code it does not show any effect. Is there a way to use automatic getter/setter generation in conjunction with further annotations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think propagating annotations to getter/setter methods would work in the general case. For example do you know what would happen if both the field and the bean properties were annotated with `@XmlElement`? For JAXB annotations I would suggest using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the field.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was looking for! '@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)' at class level notifies JAXB to use the attributes for the XML mapping (and not the getter or setter methods), see e.g. http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/34069/1763/page/3 . Thank's a lot!

Comment: I think this needs a slight review, For JPMS any runtime field reflection should be avoided at all costs - it will be removed entirely one day.

`@Getter(onMethod=@__({@YourAnnotationThatWillBeOnTheGetter}))`
to add annotations to your getter